# R : How to build heatmap with the leaflet package

Tags: r, leaflet, heat-map

I read a [post](http://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/19473) about interactive maps with R using the `leaflet` package.

In this article, the author created a heat map like this:

```
X <- cbind(lng, lat)
kde2d <- bkde2D(X, bandwidth = c(bw.ucv(X[,1]), bw.ucv(X[,2])))

x <- kde2d$x1
y <- kde2d$x2
z <- kde2d$fhat
CL <- contourLines(x , y , z)

m <- leaflet() %>%
       addTiles() 
m %>% 
  addPolygons(CL[[5]]$x, CL[[5]]$y, fillColor = "red", stroke = FALSE)
```

I am not familiar with the `bkde2d` function, so I'm wondering if this code could be generalized to any shapefiles?

What if each node has a specific weight, that we would like to represent on the heat map?

Are there other ways to create a heat map with `leaflet` map in R ?

Comment: bke2d lets you do 2d binning (kernel density estimation) for a set of points (so lng/lat pairs work well). the ks package supports kernel smoothing for data from 1- to 6-dimensions. the akima package can do interpolation (useful when you need a regular grid). it might be worth reading up on the [spatial task view](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Spatial.html) for this before attempting to produce something that may not represent the data properly.

Comment: ok, thanks for the link, I will definitely look this. Actually the bke2d function is not working that well with my data as it works in the example, and I can t figure why.

Answer (score 15):

Here's my approach for making a more generalized heat map in Leaflet using R.  This approach uses `contourLines`, like the previously mentioned blog post, but I use `lapply` to iterate over all the results and convert them to general polygons. In the previous example it's up to the user to individually plot each polygon, so I would call this "more generalized" (at least this is the generalization I wanted when I read the blog post!).

```
## INITIALIZE
library("leaflet")
library("data.table")
library("sp")
library("rgdal")
# library("maptools")
library("KernSmooth")
library("magrittr")

## LOAD DATA
## Also, clean up variable names, and convert dates
inurl <- "https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/22s8-eq8h/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
dat <- data.table::fread(inurl) %>% 
    setnames(., tolower(colnames(.))) %>% 
    setnames(., gsub(" ", "_", colnames(.))) %>% 
    .[!is.na(longitude)] %>% 
    .[ , date := as.IDate(date, "%m/%d/%Y")] %>% 
    .[]    
## MAKE CONTOUR LINES
## Note, bandwidth choice is based on MASS::bandwidth.nrd()
kde <- bkde2D(dat[ , list(longitude, latitude)],
              bandwidth=c(.0045, .0068), gridsize = c(100,100))
CL <- contourLines(kde$x1 , kde$x2 , kde$fhat)

## EXTRACT CONTOUR LINE LEVELS
LEVS <- as.factor(sapply(CL, `[[`, "level"))
NLEV <- length(levels(LEVS))

## CONVERT CONTOUR LINES TO POLYGONS
pgons <- lapply(1:length(CL), function(i)
    Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(CL[[i]]$x, CL[[i]]$y))), ID=i))
spgons = SpatialPolygons(pgons)

## Leaflet map with polygons
leaflet(spgons) %>% addTiles() %>% 
    addPolygons(color = heat.colors(NLEV, NULL)[LEVS])
```

Here's what you'll have at this point:
[image]

```
## Leaflet map with points and polygons
## Note, this shows some problems with the KDE, in my opinion...
## For example there seems to be a hot spot at the intersection of Mayfield and
## Fillmore, but it's not getting picked up.  Maybe a smaller bw is a good idea?

leaflet(spgons) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addPolygons(color = heat.colors(NLEV, NULL)[LEVS]) %>%
    addCircles(lng = dat$longitude, lat = dat$latitude,
               radius = .5, opacity = .2, col = "blue")
```

And this is what the heat map with points would look like:

[image]

Here's an area that suggests to me that I need to tune some parameters or perhaps use a different kernel:

[image]

```
## Leaflet map with polygons, using Spatial Data Frame
## Initially I thought that the data frame structure was necessary
## This seems to give the same results, but maybe there are some 
## advantages to using the data.frame, e.g. for adding more columns
spgonsdf = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr = spgons,
                                    data = data.frame(level = LEVS),
                                    match.ID = TRUE)
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
    addPolygons(data = spgonsdf,
                color = heat.colors(NLEV, NULL)[spgonsdf@data$level])
```

Comment: Scoured the interwebs trying to figure this out and this was by far the best example I found. Plugged it in to my code and it "just worked." Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks!  I've actually created a repo with several other map examples that might be useful for others https://github.com/geneorama/wnv_map_demo

Comment: Thanks for this mini-tutorial.  How did you select the `bandwidth` in `bkde2d()` ?

Comment: @the_darkside great question. In reality I fiddle with it until I get something I like, I originally developed this map specifically to examine the bandwidth assumptions. In this case I actually used `MASS::bandwidth.nrd(dat$latitude)` and `MASS::bandwidth.nrd(dat$longitude)` as the starting points. See `?MASS::kde2d` documentation which links to `bandwith.nrd`. Also see `?KernSmooth::dpik` if you're interested for another approach.

Comment: if  `gridsize = c(100,100)` does that mean there are a total of 10,000 cells?

Comment: @the_darkside yes

Comment: I don't see where the weight is specified.  The csv has a number of other columns besides lat/lon/thefts, so how is thefts the one that is being displayed when it isn't specified?

Comment: @jzadra I remember wondering the same thing. In the KDE step  `kde <- bkde2D(dat...` each *row* is converted to the density object, there is no weighting.

Comment: @geneorama I see, so this only has at max one binary indicator for each coordinate.  I'll have to figure out a way to weight it for continuous data.

Answer (score 6):

Building off of genorama's answer above, you can also convert the output of bkde2D      into a raster rather than contour lines, using the fhat values as the raster cell values

```
library("leaflet")
library("data.table")
library("sp")
library("rgdal")
# library("maptools")
library("KernSmooth")
library("raster")

inurl <- "https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/22s8-eq8h/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
infile <- "mvthefts.csv"

## LOAD DATA
## Also, clean up variable names, and convert dates
if(!file.exists(infile)){
  download.file(url = inurl, destfile = infile)
}
dat <- data.table::fread(infile)
setnames(dat, tolower(colnames(dat)))
setnames(dat, gsub(" ", "_", colnames(dat)))
dat <- dat[!is.na(longitude)]
dat[ , date := as.IDate(date, "%m/%d/%Y")]

## Create kernel density output
kde <- bkde2D(dat[ , list(longitude, latitude)],
              bandwidth=c(.0045, .0068), gridsize = c(100,100))
# Create Raster from Kernel Density output
KernelDensityRaster <- raster(list(x=kde$x1 ,y=kde$x2 ,z = kde$fhat))

#create pal function for coloring the raster
palRaster <- colorNumeric("Spectral", domain = KernelDensityRaster@data@values)

## Leaflet map with raster
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addRasterImage(KernelDensityRaster, 
                 colors = palRaster, 
                 opacity = .8) %>%
  addLegend(pal = palRaster, 
            values = KernelDensityRaster@data@values, 
            title = "Kernel Density of Points")
```

This is your output. Note that the low density values still show up as colored in the raster.

[image: Raster Output]

We can remove these low density cells with the following :

```
#set low density cells as NA so we can make them transparent with the colorNumeric function
 KernelDensityRaster@data@values[which(KernelDensityRaster@data@values < 1)] <- NA

#create pal function for coloring the raster
palRaster <- colorNumeric("Spectral", domain = KernelDensityRaster@data@values, na.color = "transparent")

## Redraw the map
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addRasterImage(KernelDensityRaster, 
                 colors = palRaster, 
                 opacity = .8) %>%
  addLegend(pal = palRaster, 
            values = KernelDensityRaster@data@values, 
            title = "Kernel Density of Points")
```

Now any raster cell with a value of less than 1 is transparent.

[image: Final Map]

If you want a binned raster, use the colorBin function rather than the colorNumeric function:

```
palRaster <- colorBin("Spectral", bins = 7, domain = KernelDensityRaster@data@values, na.color = "transparent")

## Leaflet map with raster
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addRasterImage(KernelDensityRaster, 
                 colors = palRaster, 
                 opacity = .8) %>%
  addLegend(pal = palRaster, 
            values = KernelDensityRaster@data@values, 
            title = "Kernel Density of Points")
```

[image: Binned Raster Kernel Density]

To make it smoother, simply increase the gridsize in the bkde2D function. This increases the resolution of the generated raster. (I changed it to

```
gridsize = c(1000,1000)
```

Output:

[image: Smoothed Raster]

Comment: How can you convert the legend description “Kernel Density of Points” to something more intuitive, like “Thefts per square km”? I guess there is an equation linking the bandwidth, gridsize and projection, or perhaps even kdf$fhat that describes the units.

Comment: Thanks!  I really like this answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I got an error when running the code. The message is: "Error in get: object '.xts_chob' not found". Do you know why ?

Comment: See [link](https://github.com/chao-shi-git/scrapy_ttools/issues/1#issuecomment-849428060) for solution

Answer (score 3):

An easy way of creating Leaflet heat maps in R is using the [Leaflet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) plugin. An excellent guide on how to use it can be found [here](https://rmaps.github.io/blog/posts/leaflet-heat-maps/index.html). Hope you find it useful.